# How to send Text and Images to server using NSURLConnection in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection

Hi i am very beginner in Ios and in my project i need to send "Username" and "Password"  and "UserImage" to server using NSURLConnection and for this i have inserted this three fields(username,password,userimage) in one Dictionary and i am posting this dictionary to server but using my below code details are not sending to server please help me what did i do here wrong

### my code:-

```
@interface SendingImagesToServer ()
{
    NSMutableData *body;
}
@end

@implementation SendingImagesToServer

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSData *imageData;
    UIImage * image;
    NSError *error = nil;
    image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"friendship.jpg"];
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1f);

    NSDictionary *mainDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                              @"James"  ,@"username",
                              @"1234",@"Password",
                              imageData,@"image",
                              nil];

    NSString *jsonString = [mainDict JSONRepresentation];

    NSData * webbody = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    body = [webbody mutableCopy];

    NSString *urlstr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"My url here"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"----WebKitFormBoundarycC4YiaUFwM44F6rT";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    body = [NSMutableData data];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imagename\"; filename=\"picture.png\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    if(imageData == nil && error!=nil) {
        NSLog(@"nil");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"not nill");
    }

    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Successfully sending to server");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"error is %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

@end
```

Comment: Ouch. You have a mix of JSON and multipart/form-data (and you overwrite one with the other). You try to include binary data in JSON. You don't actually create or call a request. Before anybody can actually help you, you need to specify exactly how the data should be send: multipart/form-data or JSON, if JSON how the image data is encoded (base64?), etc.

Answer (score -1):

You create the request, but don't start it anywhere in your code. Also you don't create the `NSURLConnection` anywhere (at least not in the posted part).

The easiest way to achieve this would be to simply add this line at the end of your `viewDidLoad` method :

```
NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

You can read more [here](http://NSURLConnection%20*conn%20=%20[[NSURLConnection%20alloc]%20initWithRequest:request%20delegate:self];)

Comment: ,can you please edit my code and please post working code because i am very new for IOS

Comment: what did you change here it was seems like copy and paste of my above posted code and  there was no change

Comment: As I said before : I've added the line from my answer at the end of your `viewDidLoad` implementation (line 60 in pastebin) and made sure that your `SendingImagesToServer` class conforms to `NSURLConnectionDelegate` protocol (line 1). Please read carefully.

Comment: oh sorry Losiowaty i did not see these two chnages in your updated code(    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self],NSURLConnectionDelegate protocol)

Comment: so is these two changes enough to send my fields to server?

Comment: They should be. If the server understands your request is another thing. You should consider the comment by @jcaron under your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96668/discussion-between-abhiram-and-losiowaty).